# Chrome Extension - watch variable from main JS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I would like to ask whether it is possible to place a watch over variable in main JS in Chrome Extension? I'd prefer to use Proxy (haven't checked how to use yet but seems cool).

This is what I think I can make it work, but would prefer cleaner way:

```
let currentHP;
setInterval(() => {
    const hp = getDOMVariable('hp') // custom function to retrieve global variable through DOM
    if (hp !== currentHP) {
        // do sth
    }
    currentHP = hp;
}, 1000);
```

The problem that I'm facing is I can't switch out of the `setInterval` loop since in the `content-script`, I don't have access to any global variables in the original page. And without the constant access to it, I have to use the `setInterval` to frequently retrieve data. I'm looking for a more permanent way to access the variable directly, and not through a function.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @wOxxOm the code is working. Like I said, I would prefer to have a `cleaner` way (using a Proxy, perhaps)

Comment: And what is the problem with using `Proxy`? Note that we can't help here without seeing how that variable is defined by the web site so you need to provide a proper [MCVE](/help/mcve). P.S. Currently the question is off-topic due to several reasons including the one that it attracts opinionated answers because "cleaner" is subjective.

Comment: @wOxxOm I think I understand your point of not being clear. I have updated the question. Please check again to see whether it makes more sense now

Comment: Yeah, excellent. You still need to show how the page defines the variable because the Proxy approach would work only if it's a property of some object.

Comment: @wOxxOm the problem is with how I'm retrieving data from the main JS. Since it's not directly accessed, I can't get away from using a `setInterval`

Comment: setInterval isn't related to what I asked. Trying to rephrase, you need to find how the page defines that variable in its code and show it here. Your only hope is for that variable to be a property of some other object.

Comment: It seems that you want to monitor DOM changes (the `getDOMVariable` led me to believe that), if that is the case, you can use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Comment: @Titus the `getDomVariable` is a method to retrieve JS global variable through DOM element since I don't have direct access to any of the global variable in the main script. It has nothing to do with DOM :(